# Cannot connect to todoist REST API with R

Tags: r, api, restful-authentication, todoist

I am not very good with working with API's "From scratch" so to speak. My issue here is probably more to do with my ignorance of RESTful API's than the Todoist API specifically, but I'm struggling with Todoist because all of their documentation is geared around python and I'm not sure why my feeble attempts are failing. Once I get connected/authenticated I think I'll be fine.

[Todoist documentation](https://developer.todoist.com/rest/v8/)

I've tried a couple of configurations using `httr::GET()`. I would appreciate a little push here as I get started.

Things I've tried, where `key` is my api token:

```
library(httr)
r<-GET("https://beta.todoist.com/API/v8/", add_headers(hdr))
```

for `hdr`, I've used a variety of things:

- hdr<-paste0("Authorization: Bearer", key)
- just my key

I also tried with `projects` at the end of the url

Comment: Please show us your ("feeble"?) attempts; it helps to fix your code (in your style or adjusting your style) than generate full-code from scratch. Also, I believe that Todoist requires an account, so some or many of us will not be able to actually test code, so it'll help to provide a semblance of the responses you get from them that are good-enough for one step but you can't work with for the next. Etc.

Comment: added detail. not sure it will be very helpful, and it's not much. i've also tried using a package someone developed which starts with a login (username/pwd) authentication and that didn't work either. the documentation at the repo is not up to date. (devtools::install_github("karthikram/rtodoist") )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** These are now implemented in the R package [rtodoist](https://github.com/karthik/rtodoist).

---

I think you nearly had it except the url? (or maybe it changed since then) and the header. The following works for me, replacing `my_todoist_token` with API token found [here](https://todoist.com/prefs/integrations).

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
projects_api_url <- "https://api.todoist.com/rest/v1/projects"

# to get the project as a data frame
header <- add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer ", my_todoist_token))
project_df <- GET(url = projects_api_url, header) %>%
  content("text", encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
  fromJSON(flatten = TRUE)

# to create a new project
# unfortunately no way to change the dot color associated with project
header2 <- add_headers(
  Authorization  = paste("Bearer ", my_todoist_token),
  `Content-Type` = "application/json",
  `X-Request-Id` = uuid::UUIDgenerate())

POST(url = projects_api_url, header2,
     body = list(name = "Your New Project Name"
                 # parent = parentID
                 ),
     encode = "json")

# get a project given project id
GET(url = paste0(projects_api_url, "/", project_df$id[10]),
    header) %>%
  content("text", encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
  fromJSON(flatten = TRUE)

# update a project 
POST(url = paste0(projects_api_url, "/", project_df$id[10]),
    header2, body = list(name = "IBS-AR Biometric 2019"), encode = "json")
```

Comment: thank you! I'm able to get my projects, this should allow me to get at other pieces as well. much appreciated.

Comment: @ChrisUmphlett Documentation is still lacking but I have most of the project/task actions implemented in https://github.com/karthik/rtodoist

Comment: Yup I suggested to Karthik I'll update it. A bit more documentation added (along with some breaking API changes)

Comment: @ChrisUmphlett if you would like to contribute, I'll be happy for you to do so as I think Karthik